# Nest select statement in from clause while using order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, nested

In SQL Server I try to include a select statement into a from clause while using an order by statement and I get an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'".

```
select name, value, count(distinct id) as results
from (select 'test' as name, 'test 2' as value, 5 as id)
group by name, value
```

What is the problem with my syntax and how to do what I am trying to?

the inner select statement is just a dummy example. In my case I do have a select statement with many rows where only the id is different.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `From` in the nested select

Comment: You say ORDER BY, but you do GROUP BY...

Comment: As GarethD pointed below the problem was the missing Alias name for the subquery so adding AS T after the parenthesis did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the subquery an alias, e.g.

```
select name, value, count(distinct id) as results
from (select 'test' as name, 'test 2' as value, 5 as id) AS t -- Alias Here
group by name, value;
```

This sucessfully returns:

```
name    value       results
------------------------------
test    test 2      1
```

Comment: How does this query even work, much less produce results? The inner select needs to get its data from somewhere, right?

Comment: You don't need to select from a table, if you forget about all the extraneous information, and just consider the following `SELECT 1 AS Test`, this will return a single row with a single column named `Test`. All the above query does is expand on this, by adding more columns and putting it into a sub query. For a working example, see this: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=17d62860bf2a2883b3f61a4a2e6d302a

Comment: Thanks Gareth and Sami. The problem was that I was missing the AS statement to give an alias name to the query

Comment: @GarethD True, he don't need to select from table in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the subquery alias:

```
select 
    name, value, count(distinct id) as results
from 
    (select 'test' as name, 'test 2' as value, 5 as id) SQ
group by 
    name, value;
```